# Fast obtention of all the subsets of size N in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization, complexity-theory, set

The following (unoptimal) code generates all the subsets of size N for certain subset.

This code works but, as I said, is highly unoptimal. Using an intermediate list to avoid the O(log(n)) of Set.insert doesn't seem help due to the large cost of later reconverting the list to a Set

Can anybody suggest how to optimize the code?

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set


subsetsOfSizeN :: Ord a => Int -> Set.Set a -> Set.Set (Set.Set a)
subsetsOfSizeN n s
  | Set.size s < n || n < 0 = error "subsetOfSizeN: wrong parameters"
  | otherwise = doSubsetsOfSizeN n s
 where doSubsetsOfSizeN n s
        | n == 0 = Set.singleton Set.empty
        | Set.size s == n = Set.singleton s
        | otherwise =
           case Set.minView s of
             Nothing -> Set.empty
             Just (firstS, restS) ->
               let partialN n = doSubsetsOfSizeN n restS in
               Set.map (Set.insert firstS) (partialN (n-1)) `Set.union` partialN n
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This code works but, as I said, is highly unoptimal.

Doesn't seem so terribly bad to me. The number of subsets of size `k` of a set of size `n` is `` n `choose` k `` which grows rather fast for `k ~ n/2`. So creating all the subsets must scale badly.

> Using an intermediate list to avoid the `O(log(n))` of `Set.insert` doesn't seem help due to the large cost of later reconverting the list to a Set.

Hmm, I found using lists to give better performance. Not asymptotically, I think, but a not negligible more-or-less constant factor.

But first, there is an inefficiency in your code that is simple to repair:

```
Set.map (Set.insert firstS) (partialN (n-1))
```

Note that `Set.map` must rebuild a tree from scratch. But we know that `firstS` is always smaller than any element in any of the sets in `partialN (n-1)`, so we can use `Set.mapMonotonic` that can reuse the spine of the set.

And that principle is also what makes lists attractive, the subsets are generated in lexicographic order, so instead of `Set.fromList` we can use the more efficient `Set.fromDistinctAscList`. Transcribing the algorithm yields

```
onlyLists :: Ord a => Int -> Set.Set a -> Set.Set (Set.Set a)
onlyLists n s
    | n == 0                    = Set.singleton Set.empty
    | Set.size s < n || n < 0   = error "onlyLists: out of range n"
    | Set.size s == n           = Set.singleton s
    | otherwise                 = Set.fromDistinctAscList . map Set.fromDistinctAscList $
                                                         go n (Set.size s) (Set.toList s)
      where
        go 1 _ xs = map return xs
        go k l (x:xs)
            | k == l = [x:xs]
            | otherwise = map (x:) (go (k-1) (l-1) xs) ++ go k (l-1) xs
```

which in the few benchmarks I've run is between 1.5 and 2× faster than the amended algorithm using `Set`s.

And that is in turn, in my criterion benchmarks, nearly twice as fast as [dave4420](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268763/1011995)'s.

Answer (score 14):

This is inspired by Pascal's triangle.

```
choose :: [b] -> Int -> [[b]]
_      `choose` 0       = [[]]
[]     `choose` _       =  []
(x:xs) `choose` k       =  (x:) `fmap` (xs `choose` (k-1)) ++ xs `choose` k
```

Comment: very nice, I like this one

Comment: Very elegant, congratulations :)

Answer (score 1):

```
subsets :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
subsets 0 _ = [[]]
subsets _ [] = []
subsets k (x:xs) = map (x:) (subsets (k - 1) xs) ++ subsets k xs
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a better algorithm.

Look at your final line:

```
           Set.map (Set.insert firstS) (partialN (n-1)) `Set.union` partialN n
```

Evaluating `doSubsetsOfSizeN k (Set.fromList $ 1:2:xs)` will involve evaluating `doSubsetsOfSizeN (k-1) (Set.fromList xs)` *twice* (once when inserting `1`, and once when inserting `2`). This duplication is wasteful.

Enter a better algorithm.

```
mine :: Ord a => Int -> Set.Set a -> Set.Set (Set.Set a)
mine n s | Set.size s < n || n < 0 = Set.empty
         | otherwise               = Set.foldr cons nil s !! n
    where
        nil :: Ord a => [Set.Set (Set.Set a)]
        nil = Set.singleton Set.empty : repeat Set.empty
        cons :: Ord a => a -> [Set.Set (Set.Set a)] -> [Set.Set (Set.Set a)]
        cons x sets = zipWith Set.union sets
                               (Set.empty : map (Set.map $ Set.insert x) sets)
```

`` mine 9 (Data.Set.fromList [0..18]) `seq` () `` is faster than `` subsetsOfSizeN 9 (Data.Set.fromList [0..18]) `seq` () `` and should have better asymptotic performance.

I haven't tried optimising this any further. There may be a better algorithm still.

(If the cost of `insert` and `fromList` are issues, you should consider giving back a list of lists instead of a set of sets.)

Answer (score 0):

I found this, may be it can help you

```
f []  = [[1]]
f l   = (:) [u] l'
    where 
        u  = succ (head (head l))
        l' = (++) l (map(\x->(:) u x) l)

fix f n = if (n==0) then [] else f (fix f (n-1))
```

To test it

```
$ length $ (fix f 10) => 1023 -- The empty set is always include then == 1024
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for `(:) [u] l'` rather than just `[u]:l'`? (And similarly the `(++)` and `(:)` in the definition of `l'`.)

Comment: Yes, I prefer to use this form, because I can write in my where clause, cons = uncurry (:), concat = uncurry (++) and after replace [u]:l' by cons [u] l.